# Duplicate/symlink a public Stack Overflow question to your Team account

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, questions, answers, stack-overflow-for-teams

I find some Stack Overflow questions and answers useful very frequently and I think it would be great to be able to duplicate them to my SO Team account so

1. I don't have to search for them in tons of other questions
2. My team would be aware which solution we prefer because it's in our team's feed

Is it possible? (except copying question and all answers manually)

Comment: Imo, Copy is the best way to go. Because you have a snapshot of the Question answer and no future modification will impact your Team SO. So you don't have to check every time someone add a new answer or edit an existing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're absolutely correct! We are thinking about it; we know it is a problem, and we are thinking of ways to solve this, but it's not going to be resolved in the near term.